# How to remove .php extension from URL on server and on localhost with .htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Like the title says I need to remove the .php from a URL with a .htaccess `RewriteRule`.

```
https://example.com/about.php
```

should be

```
https://example.com/about
```

**AND**

```
localhost:8080/about.php
```

should be

```
localhost:8080/about
```

---

Here is my current `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

## To internally rewrite /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: This is nice how it redirects from the .php, but when that happens it redirects from https to http.

Comment: No that is not happening inn my suggested rules. Can you post your full htaccess inn question

Comment: Added my current file

Comment: Ok so you need to replace all of your existing .htaccess with this suggested code in my answer. Do note that I don't have `http://` or `https://` anywhere in my code so if you are seeing `https -> http` happening then it might be due to something in your code or Apache config. To test that I suggest test in **Chrome dev tool** with **caching disabled** and check in Network tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your `.htaccess` file, it will remove `.php` extension from the URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: check if mod_rewrite module is enabled . create php file and write `<?php phpinfo() ?>` and open the url . make sure there is `mod_rewrite` in Loaded Modules

Comment: Your solution works on the server, but not on localhost. On localhost it is attempting to rewrite but ends up in a loop.

Comment: I changed my xampp port to 8081 and it still works as localhost:8081/about . 
maybe you are doing something else wrong .